# Is there a Java 1.5 equivalent to the Predicate<T> methods in .Net?

Tags: java, .net, collections, predicate

Specifically, I'm looking for similarly clean notation to the `Collection<T>.TrueForAll` / `Exists`, etc.

It feels smelly to have to write a foreach loop to inspect the return of a method on each object, so I'm hoping there's a better Java idiom for it.

Comment: Note: There *is* that in Java 1.8, but not in Java 1.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Predicates](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/class-use/Predicate.html) are provided in the [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) library.

Answer (score 6):

[Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org) provides first-class functions. A predicate is expressed as `F<T, Boolean>`. For example, here's a program that tests an array for the existence of a string that is all lowercase letters.

```
import fj.F;  
import fj.data.Array;  
import static fj.data.Array.array;
import static fj.function.Strings.matches;

public final class List_exists {  
  public static void main(final String[] args) { 
    final Array<String> a = array("Hello", "There", "how", "ARE", "yOU?");  
    final boolean b = a.exists(matches.f("^[a-z]*$"));  
    System.out.println(b); // true
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, no. But Apache [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has something like this: [`Predicate`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate.html)

---

**Edit**: Right, as noted in comments, Commons Collections is from pre-generics world, so <s>[Google Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787446/is-there-a-java-1-5-equivalent-to-the-predicatet-methods-in-net/787458#787458)</s> (*update*: [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)) seems like a clearly better option now. Still, Commons Collections deserves to be mentioned as it's a well-known library that does this, and also so that people know *why* not to use it. :)

I was just reading more about Google Collections in this [nice interview](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/google-collections/) with its main developers, and wanted to quote a bit that deals specifically with the "Google Collections vs. Apache Commons Collections" issue:

> **What is unique about your approach?
>   How does it differ to, for example,
>   the Apache Commons Collection?**
>
> Kevin: "Well, thank God for the Apache
>   Commons. We'd all be in bad shape
>   without libraries like this. That
>   said, sadly that particular project
>   has stalled, in a pre-generics world.
>   They do want to adopt generics, but
>   they recognize that this would involve
>   a pretty nontrivial and incompatible
>   rewrite. So far, no one seems to be
>   actively driving such an effort. At
>   Google we've been using Java 5
>   company-wide since the spring of 2005.
>   A collections library being
>   ungenerified was a deal-breaker for
>   us, because we really hate getting
>   compiler warnings. I was also
>   concerned about the many places in
>   which the Apache collections don't
>   conform to the specifications of the
>   JDK interfaces they implement."
>
> [...]
>
> Jared: "As Kevin implies, our library
>   is the only collections library I know
>   of, outside the JDK, built with Java 5
>   features: generics, enums, covariant
>   return types, etc. When writing Java 5
>   code, you want a collections library
>   that takes full advantage of the
>   language. In addition, we put enormous
>   effort into making the library
>   complete, robust, and consistent with
>   the JDK collection classes. Our
>   collection classes were much more
>   limited initially, but we've gradually
>   improved them over the last two years.
>   Since all library usage is in Google's
>   source control system, we've had the
>   flexibility to modify public
>   interfaces. An open-source project
>   like Apache Commons Collection doesn't
>   have the freedom to change its
>   behavior after the initial release.
>   Since we'll lose that flexibility once
>   Google Collections Library 1.0 is
>   released, we're eager to receive
>   feedback now so we can get things
>   right."

Comment: Commons Collections lacks generic support.

Comment: Commons Collections added generics support for 4.0, released in 2013