# Bi-directional Map in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, apache-commons

I have a simple integer-to-string mapping in Java, but I need to be able to easily retrieve string from integer, and also integer from string. I've tried Map, but it can retrieve only string from integer, it's one way:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
// This works one way:
String myString = myMap.get(myInteger);

// I would need something like:
Integer myInteger = myMap.getKey(myString);
```

Is there a right way to do it to have it both directions?

Another problem is that I only have a few constant values that don't change (`1->"low", 2->"mid", 3->"high"`, so it wouldn't be worth to go for a complicated solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487163/bidirectional-mapping-in-java-witch-rejects-entries-of-key-or-value-already-exis demonstrates a solution based on [this][1] tutorial.


  [1]: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/commons_collections/commons_collections_bidimap.htm

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use the Google Collections API for that, <strike>recently</strike> renamed to [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), specifically a [BiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap)

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the
> uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint
> enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap
> containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and
> values.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39329395/5466401

Comment: Google probably needs BiMap for specific use cases. But, why does Java not provide BiMap ? Its nice to have options in data structures & algorithms instead of having to get them from libraries or coding from scratch.

Answer (score 56):

Creating a Guava BiMap and getting its inverted values is trivial.

A simple example:

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;

public class BiMapTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BiMap<String, String> biMap = HashBiMap.create();

    biMap.put("k1", "v1");
    biMap.put("k2", "v2");

    System.out.println("k1 = " + biMap.get("k1"));
    System.out.println("v2 = " + biMap.inverse().get("v2"));
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this example illustrate that it is “not so trivial”?

Answer (score 31):

There is no bidirectional map in the Java Standard API. Either you can maintain two maps yourself or use the [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) from Apache Collections.

Comment: Like `BidiMap bidiMap = new DualHashBidiMap();`

Comment: But this dont have generic support :(

Comment: For future readers -- this does have generics support at this point

Comment: It has generic support now

Answer (score 17):

You could insert both the key,value pair and its inverse into your map structure, but would have to convert the Integer to a string:

```
map.put("theKey", "theValue");
map.put("theValue", "theKey");
```

Using map.get("theValue") will then return "theKey".

It's a quick and dirty way that I've made constant maps, which will only work for a select few datasets:

- Contains only 1 to 1 pairs
- Set of values is disjoint from the set of keys (1->2, 2->3 breaks it)

If you want to keep `<Integer, String>` you could maintain a second `<String, Integer>` map to "put" the value -> key pairs.

Comment: Furthermore, all keys and values should be different.

Comment: This answer is pure blasphemy. thats why i like it :)

Comment: This a great hack

Answer (score 11):

Apache commons collections has a [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html)

Answer (score 5):

Use Google's [BiMap](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

It is more convenient.