# How do I get a key from a HashMap by providing the value?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
private static HashMap<Script, String> scripts = new HashMap<>();

    public Script getScriptByName(String name) {
        for (String s : scripts.values()) {
            if (s.equals(name)) {
                ...
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Given this code, how can I get the key of a specific value?

Comment: If you need to do this, you should probably restructure your data. Perhaps point the map in the other direction?

Comment: Does it have to be a hashmap?  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699492/bi-directional-map-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Hashmap: How to get key from value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigate through the entries of the map instead:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : scripts.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals(name)) {
        return entry.getKey();
    }
}

return null;
```

Comment: you're missing a `)` after `scripts.entrySet()`. I can't edit due to not changing up to 6 chars

Comment: @VinceEmigh WADR, after `equals(name)`?