# How to Deploy WebApplication Using JavaSpark in Heroku Which Has StaticFilesFolder for WebComponents

Tags: heroku, spark-java

I Wanted to deploy an web application on Heroku which has to be served using staticfilesfolder in WebSocketServer.ja

```
    port(getHerokuAssignedPort());
    webSocketIdleTimeoutMillis(1000000000);
    staticFileLocation("/public");
    webSocket("/em/", WebSocketHandler.class);
    init();
```

and websocketClient.js

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port + "/em/");
```

But I was unable to server the *.html, *.css, *.js file from /public folder.It is working fine with my local system not working on heroku site.It shows application error.

Comment: It really depends on your WAR file structure. But I'd just make few experiments on the non-local deployment and then add `if (local) {...} else {...}` in my initialization code with the correct path for each.

Comment: yeah, I updated  staticFileLocation with "/public" relative to target it building still it doesn't work....

Comment: Unrelated: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699492/bi-directional-map-in-java ... for that Bi map question. You were too quick deleting your question. Besides, the answer is **no**. For a bi map in java, you need two maps.

Comment: i checked those already, thats why I have asked that question, sorry for deleting as it reduces reputation to minus levels

Comment: @SHG how to get the location of /public folder in Heroku, which is linked by github account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Bootstrap {

private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 4567;

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
     port(getHerokuAssignedPort());
     externalStaticFileLocation(getPublicFolderPath());
}

private static int getHerokuAssignedPort() {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    if (processBuilder.environment().get("PORT") != null) {
        return Integer.parseInt(processBuilder.environment().get("PORT"));
    }
    return DEFAULT_PORT;
}

private static String getPublicFolderPath() throws URISyntaxException{
    CodeSource codeSource = Bootstrap.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
    String jarDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();
    return jarDir + File.separator + "public";
}}
```

> /public directory should be in the same folder as build jar file.

Comment: are there anyways to access database from another server, while using heroku (means without using Herokudb)