# Conversion between values of different classes?

Tags: java

Say, I have a String values of "CHAR","VARCHAR", "NUMBER" and so on from one side and JDBCType.CHAR, JDBCType.VARCHAR, JDBCType.INTEGER from other side.

I can implement the conversion as simple as :

```
public static JDBCType convertFromStringToJDBCType(String datatype) {
switch(datatype) {
  case "VARCHAR":
    result = JDBCType.VARCHAR;
    break;
  case "NUMBER":
    result = JDBCType.INTEGER;
    break;
...
}
```

The downside of this approach is that I have to build the exact opposite of this function to convert values back.

What is the optimal way to implement such a conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with a "central" switch statement, as long as you don't start to "copy" it in different places. A single switch is OK, typically "trouble" starts when the "same" switch code exists in more than one place.

If at all, you could consider to put this mapping information into a distinct map `typesByString.put("VARCHAR", JDBCType.VARCHAR)` and so on.

If you want to in "both" directions, you want to look into (surprise) [bidi maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699492/bi-directional-map-in-java)!

Comment: When using approach of distinct map, what is the best way to implement reverse-conversion (from value to key - > from JDBCType.VARCHAR to "VARCHAR")?

Comment: @Michael See the update I just made. And just for the record: dont forget about accept an answer at some point ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in `valueOf(String)` method from `Enum`. Smth like

`result = JDBCType.valueOf(datatype);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Map<String, JDBCType>` and use it to convert *key to value* and *value to key*. If *value to key* you finds slow, then you can create another, opposite, `Map<JDBCType, String>`.