# Is there a Java collection or list that can return the object key given the object value?

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary, set

Is there a way to have a collection or list where I can provide a key and receive the associated object, while at the same time have the ability to provide the object and receive that object's key?

I could make two `HashMaps` that cross reference each other like:

```
HashMap <Integer, String> objectAccessor;
objectAccessor.put(5, "five");

HashMap <String, Integer> keyAccessor;
keyAccessor.put("five", 5);
```

Or I could iterator through the `keySet` until the object is matched (but that seems really inefficient).

Is there an efficient way to do this with just one collection, or are two `HashMaps` my best option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Java have a HashMap with reverse lookup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670038/does-java-have-a-hashmap-with-reverse-lookup)

Comment: If you look at Guava's `HashBiMap` [source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java), for example, you'll see that it's backed by 2 `HashMaps`. Your answer depends on if you want to import another library or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're up for using a third-party library, consider looking at Guava's [`BiMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) implementations.

For example, [`HashBiMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) is backed by two `HashMap` instances and handles the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two maps are your best option, I think. Certainly for HashMap, where even if it provided searching for a key by value, would be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) from the [gauva library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Answer (score 0):

Google collections has a [bidirectional map](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html). The library also has a lot of other nice features.