# Data Structure design design

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, frequency

Following is the scenario which i had done couple of times ..

Count the frequency of words in a paragraph.

I create a Map and store the count. SO my map contains

```
  <Today, 10>
  <the, 123>
  <hello,1>
  <dont, 20>
```

Now the other scenario comes , identifying words with count 100 or 30

I create a map of list or map of

```
<10, [today,...]>
   <123,[the,...]>
```

or 
   <10, 2>
   <123,1>
  Basically I have two maps to handle all the work..
 This works fine and any update on one , the other has to be updated.

The retrieve and inserting time is almost O(1). But this is not that memory efficient.

What other approaches can be used ?

Comment: bi-directional maps are the datastructures for this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670038/does-java-have-a-hashmap-with-reverse-lookup

Comment: I would recommend bidirectional maps as well.

Comment: @Andreas_D - Not the same thing. Bidirectional maps require that the values as well as the keys be unique. It cannot be used when, for instance, two words have the same frequency.

Comment: Ted, yes, you're right. BiMaps won't work for this task.

Comment: Is this really a big memory problem? After all, `String`s are immutable and reusable, you don't have to carry around a second copy of every word just because you hav a second map, no? Or are you worried about the memory overhead of the second map structure itself?

Comment: nope its not a big problem, just trying to figure out something better .. I know memory is aint that big issue these days.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your (word, frequency) pairs, you can create an array of them, sort by frequency, and do a binary search. This will slow down the access to O(log n) but you can get by with about half the memory, if that's the constraint.

Other than that, I don't see anything better than what you're already doing.