# 1 to 1 mapping in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am across situation where I will be changing key based on value in `HashMap`. My `HashMap` is:

```
HashMap<Key, Path>
```

Initially I am creating `Key`s for each directory `Path` and putting these entries in `HashMap`. When doing processing, I will take `Path` based on `Key` from `HashMap` and process them. In some cases I will be re-calculating `Key` for some `Path` and want to replace old `Key` with new `Key` for that `Path`. I want to keep unique Keys for unique Paths and update Entry in HashMap with either one. So I want to perform reverse of HashMap to update Key. What is best technique for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could add a new entry with the new key and remove the old one. But  if you find yourself needing to change keys, maybe a HashMap isn't the ideal structure.

Comment: Consider adding the Google Guava library and use the [HashBiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html)-class.

Comment: Bidirectional map: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670038/does-java-have-a-hashmap-with-reverse-lookup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you are looking for *Google Guava's* [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the
>   uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint
>   enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap
>   containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and
>   values.

Comment: great man, I will consider this.. you are champ, this is what I am looking for

Comment: Your link is to Google Collections, which has been deprecated for years now.  [This](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) link might be more useful.

Answer (score 3):

Add another HashMap to do the reverse mapping. Keep it in sync with the original map and that's it. I would even create a helper class that ensures all operations are synced between the two maps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a key you could do this:

```
   String oldKey = "oldKey";
   String newKey = "newKey";

   map.put(newKey, map.remove(oldKey));
```

To get a key based on value you can either use:

- Bidi map -> http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html
- Or maintain two maps, one with the values as the key and the real one with the key as the key.

---

For fun, here's how you could maintain two maps:

```
    Map<String, String> keyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String val = "someVal";
    keyMap.put("newKey", keyMap.remove(valueMap.get(val)));
    valueMap.put(val, "newKey");
```

---

Comment: How will I get old Key based on Value efficiently?

Comment: Save the key as attribute of the value

Comment: @Cowls yes Thanks, yes I am looking for Bidirection map, this will help me

Answer (score 0):

I would

```
myHashMap.remove(Key);
```

then

```
myHashMap.put( newKey, new value);
```

During an iteration of the hashMap, the removal option is not allowe.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to set a new key, use

```
hm.set(newKey, oldPath);
```

where `hm` is your `HashMap`. Then, use

```
hm.remove(oldKey)
```

to remove the old key.

Note that if you could possibly have two `Path`s with the same `Key`, then you'll have to reverse your `HashMap` to `<Path, Key>`, since one `Key` would overwrite the other. To lookup a value and retrieve its key, [use the `entrySet()` and loop through (update 1 to the linked post)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383830/1979005).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bidirectional hash is guaranteed to be 1-to-1 and there are no concerns of memory usage, this is a *pure java* solution.

```
public class BiHash<K> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K, K>  {

    public void biPut(K k1, K k2)
    {
        super.put(k1, k2);
        super.put(k2, k1);
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no need for a personal rant in your answer.  Just stick to the facts.  In the meantime, I've edited your answer to be more professional.

Answer (score 0):

Needed a solution this recently, but didn't want to rely on a plugin, so I extended the base Java class. This implementation does not allow null values.

```
public class OneToOneMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    public OneToOneMap() {
        super();
    }
    public OneToOneMap(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
    }
    public OneToOneMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        super(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }
    public OneToOneMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        super(m);
        dedup();
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m){
        super.putAll(m);
        dedup();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if( key == null || value == null ) return null;
        removeValue(value);
        return super.put(key,value);
    }

    public K getKey( V value ){
        if( value == null || this.size() == 0 ) return null;
        Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.addAll(keySet());
        for( K key : keys ){
            if( value.equals(get(key) )) return key;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public boolean hasValue( V value ){
        return getKey(value) != null;
    }
    public boolean hasKey( K key ){
        return get(key) != null;
    }

    public void removeValue( V remove ){
        V value;
        Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.addAll(keySet());
        for( K key : keys ){
            value = get(key);
            if( value == null || key == null || value.equals(remove)) remove(key);
        }        
    }
    //can be used when a new map is assigned to clean it up
    public void dedup(){
        V value;
        Set<V> values = new HashSet<>();
        Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.addAll(keySet());
        for( K key : keys ){
            value = get(key);
            if( value == null || key == null || values.contains(value) ) remove(key);
            else values.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```